# Extract Assembly Version from DLL using Python

Tags: python, windows, file-attributes, versioninfo

I'm trying to extract some version information from a DLL using python. I read this question:
[Python windows File Version attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580924/python-windows-file-version-attribute)

It was helpful, but I also need to get the 'Assembly version' from the DLL. It's there when I right click and look on the versions tab, but not sure how I extract this with python.

On this page:
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get_dll_version.html

Tim Golden says:

> You can use the slightly more messy
>   language-dependent code in the demos
>   which come with pywin32 to find the
>   strings in the box beneath it.

Can someone point me to the example that might be useful? I looked in the win32api directories but there's nothing obvious. Would I find a solution there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get at this information by using native code. The usual way of obtaining the assembly info is by running .Net code (e.g. C#). So I'm guessing in order to be able to do the same from python you'll need to run some .Net python interpreter. See for example http://pythonnet.github.io/

Answer (score 4):

If you would rather not introduce a dependency on Python.Net, you can also use the win32 api directly:

```
from win32api import GetFileVersionInfo, LOWORD, HIWORD

def get_version_number (filename):
   info = GetFileVersionInfo (filename, "\\")
   ms = info['FileVersionMS']
   ls = info['FileVersionLS']
   return HIWORD (ms), LOWORD (ms), HIWORD (ls), LOWORD (ls)
```

Source: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get_dll_version.html

Comment: This requires `pywin32` I believe