# How can I get the properties of a DLL with Python?

Tags: python, windows, api

I want to get the properties(*file version, company, language, etc*) of a DLL file using Python and the Windows API.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470032/extract-assembly-version-from-dll-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/file/tip/win32/Demos/getfilever.py)

```
import os, win32api

ver_strings=('Comments','InternalName','ProductName', 
    'CompanyName','LegalCopyright','ProductVersion', 
    'FileDescription','LegalTrademarks','PrivateBuild', 
    'FileVersion','OriginalFilename','SpecialBuild')
fname = os.environ["comspec"]
d=win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(fname, '\\')
## backslash as parm returns dictionary of numeric info corresponding to VS_FIXEDFILEINFO struc
for n, v in d.iteritems():
    print n, v

pairs=win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(fname, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation')
## \VarFileInfo\Translation returns list of available (language, codepage) pairs that can be used to retreive string info
## any other must be of the form \StringfileInfo\%04X%04X\parm_name, middle two are language/codepage pair returned from above
for lang, codepage in pairs:
    print 'lang: ', lang, 'codepage:', codepage
    for ver_string in ver_strings:
        str_info=u'\\StringFileInfo\\%04X%04X\\%s' %(lang,codepage,ver_string)
        ## print str_info
        print ver_string, repr(win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(fname, str_info))
```

(requires [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)).