# How check application verision information in PySide

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, build, pyinstaller

I created EXE file with `Python (PySide)` + `PyInstaller`. Once I try to use

> print QtGui.QApplication.applicationVersion()

I don't see valid version in x.x.x.x format of the application.

Are there any built-in functions in PySide instead of this, or maybe should I use other library for it?

**PS.** I don't believe that Python doesn't have any methods to extract information about EXE :)

Comment: Found solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580924/python-windows-file-version-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way to do it:

```
import win32api    

def get_version_info():
    try:
        filename = APP_FILENAME
        return get_file_properties(filename)['FileVersion']
    except BaseException, err:
        log_error(err.message)
        return '0.0.0.0'

def get_file_properties(filename):
    """
    Read all properties of the given file return them as a dictionary.
    """
    propNames = ('Comments', 'InternalName', 'ProductName',
        'CompanyName', 'LegalCopyright', 'ProductVersion',
        'FileDescription', 'LegalTrademarks', 'PrivateBuild',
        'FileVersion', 'OriginalFilename', 'SpecialBuild')

    props = {'FixedFileInfo': None, 'StringFileInfo': None, 'FileVersion': '0.0.0.0'}

    try:
        # backslash as parm returns dictionary of numeric info corresponding to VS_FIXEDFILEINFO struc
        print filename
        fixedInfo = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(filename, '\\')
        props['FixedFileInfo'] = fixedInfo
        props['FileVersion'] = "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (fixedInfo['FileVersionMS'] / 65536,
                fixedInfo['FileVersionMS'] % 65536, fixedInfo['FileVersionLS'] / 65536,
                fixedInfo['FileVersionLS'] % 65536)

        # \VarFileInfo\Translation returns list of available (language, codepage)
        # pairs that can be used to retreive string info. We are using only the first pair.
        lang, codepage = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(filename, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation')[0]

        # any other must be of the form \StringfileInfo\%04X%04X\parm_name, middle
        # two are language/codepage pair returned from above

        strInfo = {}
        for propName in propNames:
            strInfoPath = u'\\StringFileInfo\\%04X%04X\\%s' % (lang, codepage, propName)
            ## print str_info
            strInfo[propName] = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(filename, strInfoPath)

        props['StringFileInfo'] = strInfo
    except BaseException, err:
        log_error(err.message)
    return props
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/pysideversion.html).

There's everything you're looking for !

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, however this link shows how we can extract version of PySide framework. I am looking for version about compiled aaplication

Comment: Isn't the QtCore version what you're looking for ?

Comment: No, I am looking for version about compiled application