# Get Application Name from .exe file in python

Tags: python, winapi, pywin

I am getting both the currently active window title and exe filepath with the code below

```
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    _, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    if hwnd != 0 or pid != 0:
        try:
            hndl =     win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, pid)
            self.newExe = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(hndl, 0)
            self.newWindowTitle = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        except:
            self.newExe = ''
            self.newWindowTitle = ''
```

the issue is that although it often is, the window title is not always the application name (the name the users understand as the main part of an application) and this is what I need. for example from calc.exe get Calculator withiout relying on the window title.

the purpose is to create a script that will log in an xml comparative use of any software on a computer

Is this possible?

Comment: First of all you need to define "application name".

Comment: in this case it means the name users know an application by. for example chrome.exe -> Google Chrome

Comment: In that case what you ask for is in general impossible. There's no a priori reason for an executable to contain its official product name in a single well defined place.

Comment: is there possibly a way to compare the exe to a list of running programs on the computer and get information about the software from the system?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I guess that the best you can do is to read the version info resource from the executable and report the `FileDescription` field. That's what tools like Process Explorer do.

Comment: So try the code from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7993095/505088

Comment: Note: Binary images are not required to contain a [VERSIONINFO resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Windows applications store information such as this inside their resource tables. There are API calls that can be used to extract this.

The following extracts the file description from a given application:

```
import win32api

def getFileDescription(windows_exe):
    try:
        language, codepage = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(windows_exe, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation')[0]
        stringFileInfo = u'\\StringFileInfo\\%04X%04X\\%s' % (language, codepage, "FileDescription")
        description = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(windows_exe, stringFileInfo)
    except:
        description = "unknown"
        
    return description
    
    
print(getFileDescription(r"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"))
```

The output is:

```
Internet Explorer
```

You could therefore pass the result of your call to `win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx()` to this function.