# GetFileVersionInfo() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, getfileversion

I'm trying to create a simple script that shows file information, but I'm running into this message error : `GetFileVersionInfo() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

While the first two information work great

```css
import os
import os.path, time
from win32api import GetFileVersionInfo

print ('last modified: %s ' % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('c:/Windows/System32/apss.dll')))
print ("created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime('C:/Windows/System32/apss.dll')))
print ('File version : %s' % GetFileVersionInfo('apss.dll','c:/Windows/System32/apss.dll'))
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580924/python-windows-file-version-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GetFileVersionInfo()` like this:

```
GetFileVersionInfo(filename, subblock)
```

`filename` should be the full filename. In your case it is `'c:/Windows/System32/apss.dll'`.

`subblock` should be `'\\'` or `'\\VarFileInfo\\Translation'`.

See [ActiveState's Docs on `GetFileVersionInfo()`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32api__GetFileVersionInfo_meth.html) for more information.