# How can I access an applications 'File Description'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file, winapi

I am attempting to get a list of open application names. 
I have had success in finding their path and executable name using libraries such as win32gui and win32process, but no avail in finding the file description.

For clarification, here is what I am trying to find:
[image]

I can get the associative path and application name (Code.exe in this case), but I am looking for the 'Visual Studio Code' information.

It would also be nice to have access to other details, but this is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the function called getFileProperties(fname) useful. It returns a dict which you can key into like this: `['StringFileInfo']['FileDescription']`. The function is defined at the link below.

[Python windows File Version attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580924/python-windows-file-version-attribute)