# add copyright to file properties using python 3

Tags: python, properties

I wish to add copyright info to many (hundreds) of jpeg files.

This post isn't quite what I'm looking for:
[How to access a file's properties on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580924/how-to-access-a-files-properties-on-windows#7993095)

The exif package is pretty cool:
https://gitlab.com/TNThieding/exif

I am able to add a "Copyright" attribute using the exif package, however content does not appear when I view in Windows Explorer. I have also tried for "Comments"

Presumably, this is because Copyright and Comments are file properties and not exif attributes (though they all appear collectively in the "File Properties" pop-up window).

Is it possible to modify either Copyright or Comments properties using Python 3?

Cheers

EDIT:

Here's a view in Explorer that includes some files with copyright and some without:
[image: Windows Explorer screen cap]

And a screen capture of the file properties pane:
[image: File properties screen capture]

Comment: Do you have an example of an image, any image, which does show copyright data in Windows Explorer? If not, then maybe Windows Explorer simply does not show this and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: screen captures added to post