# How to get the application name having the process name using python?

Tags: python, windows, taskmanager

I want to get the name of running application having the process name for e.g.     pycharm64.exe-->Pycharm or chrome.exe --> Google chrome

Here's what I have achieved so far

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()

def get_process_name(hwnd):
"""Get applicatin filename given hwnd."""
try:
    _, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)

    for p in c.query('SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = %s' % str(pid)):
        exe = p.Name
        # print(GetFileVersionInfo(exe))
        break
    return exe
except:
    return None


while True :
time.sleep(3) 
print(get_process_name(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()))
```

Comment: Okay, and what does this return that is different from expected?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it returns the process name but I want the application name for further steps in the program. e.g. POWERPNT.EXE is what I get when PowerPoint is the running application

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the `exe = P.Name` line, and look at all the other attributes of `p`, can you find what you want?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried this but there are only two other attributes Handle which returns the handle number and __len__ attribute

Comment: If you want the window title try (and google) `win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())`

Comment: @viilpe The problem with this approach is that you don't get program name but you get title of window for e.g. if I tried to open a file in powerpoint what I get is "open" what I want is to get the program name itself "powerpoint"

Comment: @MohamedGamal ok [then take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580924/how-to-access-a-files-properties-on-windows). For PowerPoint:  getFileProperties('path to exe')['StringFileInfo']['FileDescription'] -> 'Microsoft PowerPoint'

Comment: I found a solution that works ! Using the file description I take the path of the process exe and then using win32api.GetFileVersionInfo I got the file description name as  intended. here's the code :                   
        `p = psutil.Process(pid)
        ExecutablePath = p.exe()
        langs = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(ExecutablePath, r'\VarFileInfo\Translation')
        key = r'StringFileInfo\%04x%04x\FileDescription' % (langs[0][0], langs[0][1])
        description=(win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(ExecutablePath, key))`

Comment: Thanks @viilpe ! I found the same solution as yours :) maybe yours is a bit cleaner